# How to change font size and color in second line of text on a Winforms button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, colors, line

```
 this.Controls.Add(button);
 button.Font = new Font("Arial", 8);
 button.Name = "btn" + idDanych;
 button.Width = 100;
 button.Height = 100;
 button.Location = new Point(0, 0);
 button.Text = "…" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "…";
 button.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

How can I change the font size and color in the button's second line of text?

Comment: The framework Button only supports one font at a time - you'll need to use a different control (or create a composite control) and handle the `Click` event of that control.

Comment: Could You tell me which one control?

Comment: search for .net windows button control.  There are some free ones and some that you have to buy.  I've also seen people use a read-only, disabled `RichTextBox` with clever styling to "mimic" a button

Comment: ...it is possible with the standard .Net Button control; just not with the `.Text` and `.Font` properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible using the `.Text` property...

...but you can create a dynamic Bitmap to take the place of the Text, allowing you to format it however you want:

[image: Button with Custom String Rendering via an Image]

```
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Name = "btn" + idDanych;
        button.Width = 100;
        button.Height = 100;
        button.Location = new Point(0, 0);

        button.Text = "";
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(button.ClientRectangle.Width, button.ClientRectangle.Height);
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            G.Clear(button.BackColor);

            string line1 = "( " + Wieszak + " ) " + Haczyk;
            string line2 = KodEAN;

            StringFormat SF = new StringFormat();
            SF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            SF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            using (Font arial = new Font("Arial", 12))
            {
                Rectangle RC = button.ClientRectangle;
                RC.Inflate(-5, -5);
                G.DrawString(line1, arial, Brushes.Black, RC, SF);
            }

            using (Font courier = new Font("MS Courier", 24))
            {
                SF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                G.DrawString(line2, courier, Brushes.Red, button1.ClientRectangle, SF);
            }
        }
        button.Image = bmp;
        button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

        this.Controls.Add(button);
```

You'll have to figure out the best combination of font sizes, StringFormat layouts, and/or positioning to make it look as desired.  There are other DrawString() overloads to render the text in different ways.

Note that there will be a difference in how the control highlights, however.  On my system, the entire area of the standard button highlights when the mouse enters.  With this approach only the **border** will highlight since the entire middle of the button is a static image.

Comment: Super. But how can i change border and background?

Comment: It's possible, but it gets trickier the more things you want to change, as you have to start doing more and more to make it behave properly under all scenarios.  If you want to completely customize it, I agree with the others that you're probably better off searching for a complete customizable button control on the web...

Comment: I want change only background and border could you help me wiht that?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible with the standard [`System.Windows.Forms.Button` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx) (of which, I assume, `button` is an instance): The font size and color apply to all of the text; you cannot change these properties for just one part of the text.

(By the way, the second line of text in your button is an empty line, so you would probably not notice a different font or color anyway. Did you mean the third line of text?)

Comment: OK. So what I should to use to get effect of button with different colors of text

Comment: @harbii: If you want to use the standard `Button` class, forget about it. Otherwise, you have two options: (a) implement your own user control (fairly advanced); or (b) look for a third-party controls library that supports what you need (easier but more expensive than DYI). Two popular suppliers of such controls libraries are Telerik and Infragistics… perhaps start looking there.