# WinForms: Button with two lines, one above the other

Tags: c#, winforms, button, imagebutton

I need to put two lines as text in a WinForms button so I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203383/how-to-change-font-size-and-color-in-second-line-of-text-on-a-winforms-button) solution. I need first line, that above, to be printed in black color, and second line, that under the first one, to be printed in red color. My problem is that background rectangle is not transparent. I need background rectangle to be transparent so I have done some improvements but without success. Also first line is printed at the top not at center (vertical) and the distance between two lines (line spacing) there is too much separation. I would like to reduce it as well and center in vertical the two lines within the button. Below the code.

```
    private void TextButton(Button btn, string line1, string line2)
    {
        btn.Text = String.Empty;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(btn.ClientRectangle.Width, btn.ClientRectangle.Height);

        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            G.Clear(btn.BackColor);             

            StringFormat SF = new StringFormat();               
            SF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            SF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            using (Font tahoma = new Font("Tahoma", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold))
            {
                Rectangle RC = btn.ClientRectangle;                 
                RC.Inflate(-5, -5);
                G.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent,RC.X,RC.Y,RC.Width,RC.Height);
                G.DrawString(line1, tahoma, Brushes.Black, RC, SF);                 
            }

            using (Font tahoma2 = new Font("Tahoma", 12))
            {                   
                SF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                G.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent,btn.ClientRectangle.X,btn.ClientRectangle.Y,btn.ClientRectangle.Width,btn.ClientRectangle.Height);
                G.DrawString(line2, tahoma2, Brushes.Red, btn.ClientRectangle, SF);
            }
        }

        btn.Image = bmp;
        btn.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    }
```

Comment: why not create custom control?

Comment: @LeiYang It's a legacy project, so creating now a user control I think it has no sense in a project of this type.This project uses DotNetSkin.SkinControls style for buttons.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://dotnetrix.co.uk/button.htm

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved. Below my solution.

```
private void TextButton(Button btn, string line1, string line2)
{
    btn.Text = String.Empty;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(btn.ClientRectangle.Width, btn.ClientRectangle.Height);

    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        G.Clear(Color.Transparent);          <----- I have set this
        G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit; <--- This to avoid bad text within bitmap
        G.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;     <--- Also this to avoid bad text within bitmap

        StringFormat SF = new StringFormat();               
        SF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        SF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        using (Font tahoma = new Font("Tahoma", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold))
        {
            Rectangle RC = new Rectangle(btn.ClientRectangle.X, btn.ClientRectangle.Y + 30, btn.ClientRectangle.Width, btn.ClientRectangle.Height-30);                 
            RC.Inflate(-5, -5);

            G.DrawString(line1, tahoma, Brushes.Black, RC, SF);                 
        }

        using (Font tahoma2 = new Font("Tahoma", 12))
        {   
            Rectangle RC = new Rectangle(btn.ClientRectangle.X, btn.ClientRectangle.Y + 30, btn.ClientRectangle.Width, btn.ClientRectangle.Height-30);
            RC.Inflate(-5, -5);
            SF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;                
            G.DrawString(line2, tahoma2, Brushes.Red, RC, SF);
        }
    }

    btn.Image = bmp;
    btn.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
}
```